# Cometd: How long does the clientId last?

Tags: java, cometd

I've tried to track this down in the docs, but I don't see it anywhere.

In CometD, how long does the clientId live?

So, a client logs in and handshakes successfully.  Now they have a clientId that is associated with their session on the server.  At what point is that clientID no longer valid?

We need to reliably ensure clients have received messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question, there is no limit to the duration of the `clientId` (also known as session id).
However, server applications can decide to have the client re-handshake and get a new session id, if they feel like.

The second "question" about reliably deliver messages to clients is unrelated from the first. If you meant the two to be connected in some way, they are not.

In order to reliably deliver messages to clients, CometD offers the [acknowledgement extension](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_extensions_acknowledge).

Comment: In the docs it says message ack is not a guarantee in case of long failures.  How long is that?  Also, is there an event when the time is exceeded?

Comment: "Long" failures are those that exceed the `maxInterval` configuration parameter. When a session is removed from the server, either explicitly by the application or because of a timeout due to failures, listeners are invoked, in particular instances of `Session.RemoveListener` and `BayeuxServer.SessionListener`.

Comment: Yes, the Java client supports the ack extension.

Comment: Great, is that in the docs somewhere (how to enable the extension on the java Client)?

Comment: Mmm, it's not in the docs because I thought it would be enough to figure it out from the [javadocs](https://docs.cometd.org/current/apidocs/). I'll add it. It's `BayeuxClient.addExtension(new AckExtension())`.

Comment: You should know by now -- its *never* enough :)  Thanks for the pointer to the javadocs.

Comment: Perhaps a link from the docs to the javadocs in the message acknowledge section for those interested in using it with the Java client.